# Trying to install R 3.6.1, but having issue in ubuntu

Tags: package-management, r

I am having installing latest update of R in ubuntu (18.04). I looked at so many previous suggestions, but yet not able to resolve the issue. I am still trying, any help or suggestion will be great.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed

          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed

          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`apt-cache policy r-base` yield:

```
r-base:

Installed: (none)  
Candidate: 3.6.1-3disco
Version table:    
     3.6.1-3disco 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/     
Packages
     3.6.1-1disco 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/     
Packages
     3.6.0-2disco 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/     
Packages
     3.6.0-1disco 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/     
Packages
     3.5.3.20190412-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64     
Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu bionic/main i386     
Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Looks like you have unwisely added wrong-version sources. A Bionic (18.04) system can run Disco (19.04) packages...but only at the cost of breaking all package management and all future upgrades. Generally not a price worth paying, several better methods are available. If you are not good at version de-conflicting, I would recommend steering clear of those PPAs, too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you pleas guide me through this, so I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install 19.04 (`disco`) version of `r-base` whilst you're using 18.04 (`bionic`), that's why it throws an errors.

You have to remove the `disco` repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
```

Then replace it with `bionic` which is compatible with your current system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

<sub>[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for guidance. It is perfectly working now.

Comment: Worked for me too, using Mint 19.3 (based on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic).